# I get incomplete titles with Gnews during web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape googlenews with the gnews package. However, I get a lot of incomplete titles. I mean that for some reason the title is cut off and ellipses (...) appear in many of the news items.

```
from gnews import GNews
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2022, 1, 4)
google_news = GNews(start_date=start, end_date=end)
rsp = google_news.get_news("IA|Inteligencia Artificial|inteligencia artificial|Inteligencia artificial")
print(rsp)
```

When I print it I get (I show only the first result):

```
[{'title': 'La Comunidad de Madrid emplea la inteligencia artificial para ... - Comunidad de Madrid |', 'description': 'La Comunidad de Madrid emplea la inteligencia artificial para ...  Comunidad de Madrid |', 'published date': 'Mon, 03 Jan 2022 08:00:00 GMT'
```

Does anyone know the solution. Thanks guys!

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it. That's how the title is formatted on google news. [your search](https://news.google.com/search?q=IA%7CInteligencia%20Artificial%7Cinteligencia%20artificial%7CInteligencia%20artificial&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen)

Answer (score -1):

Please refrain from using the Gnews title as it lacks sufficient content; it only provides an abstract. Instead, utilize the Gnews URL to access the website and then employ news scraping libraries to extract the title, content, and publication date in a structured manner.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).